# How map throw forEach() inside the filter() in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

Here I have a problem mapping throw forEach() inside the filter(), I'm trying to **filter products** so **for each product object** I want to get to the **product.categories array**, and **for each** product category I want to **check** if the **product category id === the page category id** and then **map** throw them, and display the product that matches, but nothing gets displayed.

```js
<div>
    {products.filter(filterProduct => filterProduct.categories.forEach(eachProductCategory => eachProductCategory.id === category.id)).map(product => (
                              <Product />
</div>
```

Comment: Code is incomplete

Comment: @Abdulrahman Are you trying to return matched objects from two arrays?... your question isn't clear explain a little more and post original JSON response and expected JSON response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `.some` instead of `forEach`

```
<div>
  {products
    .filter((filterProduct) =>
      filterProduct.categories.some(
        (eachProductCategory) => eachProductCategory.id === category.id
      )
    )
    .map((product) => (
      <Product />
    ))}
</div>
```

`forEach` doesn't return anything that was the problem

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach